# How to use Ubuntu 20.04 in Mac M2 chip

Tags: ros

I'm currently using a Mac equipped with the M2 chip and I'm eager to start my journey of learning ROS 1. I've been researching the compatibility between my hardware and the required operating system. While I understand that ROS 1 doesn't supports Ubuntu 22.04, I'm curious if it's possible to use Ubuntu 20.04 for learning ROS 1 on my Mac with the M2 chip.
Is there any alternative options for setting up ROS 1 on my M2 chip Mac.

Answer (score 1):

While it is almost impossible to directly get ROS1 working on Apple Silicon, there are a few alternatives that I have used:

- Robostack: https://github.com/RoboStack/ros-noetic - Although their package support is limited, it is quite an impressive framework and workaround.
- Parallels or any Virtual Machine: Here is a tutorial, https://yangrobotics.com/ubuntu-and-ros-setup-on-m1-macbook-air
- UTM (Universal Turing Machine)
- Docker: This would be my suggestion. There are a few good docker images out there with GUI support. If you can get it running on your system, that would be most hassle free way to get it working.